# How To Insert Spaces Between Characters of a String Using COBOL?

Tags: cobol

Given this MOVE statement in COBOL:

```
    MOVE "ABCDEFGH" TO WORK-AREA.
```

How should WORK-AREA be coded so that a space will appear between each source character (i.e. WORK-AREA will contain "A B C D E F G H")?

```
01  WORK-AREA PIC ?
```

Comment: You have to be careful with tags. Each tag has a description. If the tag does not fit, wearing it will get you all types of hassle.

Comment: The PIC clause for WORK-AREA should be "XBXBXBXBXBXBXBX"

Comment: Ah, and still with the trailing X.

Comment: Trailing "X" is actually good, no?  8 character source string, therefore, 8 "X"s and 7 "B"s in the PIC clause for the target?

Comment: You are correct. I'm so used to it, I didn't even notice the change this time :-)

Answer (score 1):

COBOL provides a set of picture editing characters that can be used to modify data upon moving data into a field (things like left-zero suppression or commas when formatting numbers, or inserting certain characters into text fields). One of those is the simple insertion character `B` for blank, meaning you should be able to just use:

```
PIC XBXBXBXBXBXBXBX
```

---

For more complicated modifications (though not needed in this specific case, you may want to do something like reordering), I'll put forward another possibility using `move corresponding` (for mass transferring named fields) just in case:

```
01  COMP-AREA-UNION.
    03  COMP-AREA           PIC X(8).
    03  COMP-AREA-NAMED     REDEFINES COMP-AREA.
        05  AREA-A          PIC X.
        05  AREA-B          PIC X.
        05  AREA-C          PIC X.
        05  AREA-D          PIC X.
        05  AREA-E          PIC X.
        05  AREA-F          PIC X.
        05  AREA-G          PIC X.
        05  AREA-H          PIC X.
01  WORK-AREA-UNION.
    03  WORK-AREA           PIC X(15).
    03  WORK-AREA-NAMED     REDEFINES WORK-AREA.
        05  AREA-A          PIC X.
        05  FILLER          PIC X VALUE SPACE.
        05  AREA-B          PIC X.
        05  FILLER          PIC X VALUE SPACE.
        05  AREA-C          PIC X.
        05  FILLER          PIC X VALUE SPACE.
        05  AREA-D          PIC X.
        05  FILLER          PIC X VALUE SPACE.
        05  AREA-E          PIC X.
        05  FILLER          PIC X VALUE SPACE.
        05  AREA-F          PIC X.
        05  FILLER          PIC X VALUE SPACE.
        05  AREA-G          PIC X.
        05  FILLER          PIC X VALUE SPACE.
        05  AREA-H          PIC X.
```

As with most COBOL programs, it's about 80% data division, and the code is the relatively simple:

```
MOVE "ABCDEFGH" TO COMP-AREA.
MOVE CORRESPONDING COMP-AREA-NAMED TO WORK-AREA-NAMED.
```

At that point, `WORK-AREA` should contain `A B C D E F G H`. Unless I've missed a full stop from my code somewhere, in which case the compiler will have given you 120,000 lines of errors :-)

Comment: `PICTURE XBXBXBXBXBXBXBX` has been available since the first COBOL. _See_ [COBOL 60 Report](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_codasylCOB_6843924/page/n101/mode/2up), page VI-30.